# How to keep seeder files separate and clean in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5, psr-4

I want to keep my seeder files separate. for example `UsersTableSeeder.php` , `PostsTableSeeder.php` and then call them in main seeder file (`DatabaseSeeder.php`) :

**Example:**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
         $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
         $this->call(PostsTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

**usersTableSeeder.php :**

```
<?php namespace App\Seeds;

    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    use App\User;

    class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

        public function run()
        {
            //DB::table('users')->delete();

            // user1
            User::create(array(
                'name' => 'ahmad',
                'email' => 'ahmad@ahmad.com',
                'password' => 'ahmad'
            ));
        }
    }
```

my `UsersTableSeeder.php` and `PostsTableSeeder.php` files are in the same 
directory that `DatabaseSeeder.php` is.

should I use `psr-4` autoloading ? how?

Comment: Doesn't what you posted work fine?

Comment: It gives me:   [ReflectionException] Class UsersTableSeeder does not exist !  in console

Comment: And the file `database/seeders/UsersTableSeeder.php` exists with that exact file name, and it contains a `class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder` declaration? Laravel's default Composer setup should already autoload these correctly. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php

Comment: I will edit the question!

Comment: got the answer! you where right ! ! thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Composer.json configuration

`composer.json` has a `autoload` key to configure additional autoload paths.
You can give it a try:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    }
```

*Example from my composer.json*

Remove the namespace line from your seeder classes. They are found by the `classmap` entries now.

## Explicit namespaces

OR

Keep the namespaces and add them in calls to `->call()`.
Wherever you write a classname you can fully qualify the class with its namespace (should be `\database\seeds\YourClass::class`, which can depend on your `composer.json` settings), or add a use statement at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to run `composer dump-autoload`. It worked for me.

As a side note, it'd be cleaner to use PSR-4 for seeds and migrations (tests already do).